# Multi-step form with onSubmit handler (pure JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am playing around with some code from the internet to try and create a mock dog walking appointment scheduling application. So far I have my multi-step form which works as should, however I have been trying to move on to starting the submit handling, and realised that as the 'next' button is changed to 'submit' (`innerHTML`), in the JavaScript, I am not sure where to put the `onSubmit()` handling functionality..

The challenge is that I am not allowed to use any server side programming, only HTML, CSS, JS and jQuery. Handling the form seems straight-forward enough but I am unsure where to implement the `onSubmit()` function.

Please go easy on me, it is a university challenge and JS is not my strong point, I have tried looking online but the only suggestions I have are for putting the onSubmit into the button itself, which would be the obvious option but as it's a multi-step form the submit button is not coded into the HTML.

https://codepen.io/caitlinmooneyx/pen/PoGqMaG

HTML

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="" class="col-sm-6">

            <div class="tab"> 
                <h3>Book your dog walk now</h3>
                <!-- BOOKING FORM -->
                <div class="row">
                    <p>Tell us about yourself first..</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" id="fname" placeholder="First Name" name="fname" required>
                    <input type="text" id="lname" placeholder="Last Name" name="lname" required>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <input type="number" id="number" placeholder="Contact Number" name="Number" required>
                    <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email">
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <p>When should we pick your dog up?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="date" id="sdate" class="datepicker" name="sdate" onchange="checkStartDate()" required>
                    <select name="stime" id="stime" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Choose a time</option>
                        <option value="nine">9:00</option>
                        <option value="hnine">9:30</option>
                        <option value="ten">10:00</option>
                        <option value="hten">10:30</option>
                        <option value="eleven">11:00</option>
                        <option value="heleven">11:30</option>
                        <option value="twelve">12:00</option>
                        <option value="htwelve">12:30</option>
                        <option value="one">13:00</option>
                        <option value="hone">13:30</option>
                        <option value="two">14:00</option>
                        <option value="htwo">14:30</option>
                        <option value="three">15:00</option>
                    </select>
                    <select name="duration" id="duration" required>
                        <option value="" selected disabled hidden>Duration</option>
                        <option value="halfhour">30 mins</option>
                        <option value="onehour">1 hour</option>
                        <option value="onehalfhour">1.5 hours</option>
                        <option value="twohour">2 hours</option>

                    </select>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                    <p>Where should we pick up/drop off your dog?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div id="locationField">
                        <input
                               id="autocomplete"
                               placeholder="Start typing your address..."
                               onFocus="geolocate()"
                               type="text"
                               required
                               />
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="tab">
                <h3>Now tell us more about your dog..</h3>

                <div class="row">
                    <input type="text" id="dogname" placeholder="Dog Name" name="dogname" required>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <p>What breed are they?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <select class="breeds"></select>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <p>Their favourite places?</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="parks" name="parks" value="Parks">
                    <label for="parks"> Parks</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="forests" name="forests" value="Forests">
                    <label for="forests"> Forests</label><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="beaches" name="beaches" value="Beaches">
                    <label for="beaches"> Beaches</label>
                </div>

                <div class="row">
                    <p>Anything else we should know? (Favourite toys, places to avoid etc)</p>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <textarea></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div style="overflow:auto;">
                <div style="float:right;">
                    <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
                    <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
                <span class="step"></span>
                <span class="step"></span>
            </div>

        </form>
```

CSS

```
    form p {
    margin: 1em 0 .5em 1em;
}

form {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    padding: 1.5em;
    /*margin-right: 6em;*/
}

input, select, textarea {
    margin: 1em;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 45%;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: auto;
    margin: .5em 1em 0 1em;
}

input[type="date"] {
    color: #aaa!important;
}

#locationField > input {
    width: 290%!important;
}

input.invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
}

.tab {
    display: none;
}

.step {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.step.active {
    opacity: 1;
    background-color: #fac123;
}
```

JS

```
    // ~~~ tab functionality

var currentTab = 0; // current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
showTab(currentTab); // display the current tab

function showTab(n) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";

    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }

    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function nextPrev(n) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;

    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";

    currentTab = currentTab + n;

    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        //...the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
    }

    showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
    var x, y, i, s, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    s = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("select");
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        if (y[i].value == "") {
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].value == "") {
            s[i].className += " invalid";
            valid = false;
        }
    }

    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {

    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    x[n].className += " active";
}

// ~~~ dog breed selector

const BREEDS_URL = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';

const select = document.querySelector('.breeds');

fetch(BREEDS_URL)
    .then(res => {
    return res.json();
})
    .then(data => {
    const breedsObject = data.message;
    const breedsArray = Object.keys(breedsObject);
    for (let i = 0; i < breedsArray.length; i++) {
        const option = document.createElement('option');
        option.value = breedsArray[i];
        option.innerText = breedsArray[i];
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
    console.log(breedsArray);
});

// ~~~ basic form validation

// ~~~ date validation

function checkStartDate() {
    var startDate = document.getElementById('sdate').value;
    var selectedStartDate = new Date(startDate);
    var now = new Date();
    if (selectedStartDate < now) {
        alert("Start date must be in the future");
        $("#sdate").addClass("invalid");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easy to have different buttons rather than changing their text? To have more control over the functionality and simplify the logic, I would suggest to have a wrapper on each step with its own buttons and bind event to submit as you would to Next button on step one. Otherwise, when you update the button text, unbind any previous click events and bind a new one.

Comment: You know, I knew there was a simple solution but I couldn't figure it out haha. Thats what three sleepless nights in a row does to you! Silly me. Thanks for your help @Dave!

Comment: I will leave the question open for today to see if anyone can suggest the harder solution for my notes at least, but for this the simpler option will do me grand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution could be to have a submit button that you hide by default (on the first tab) and show once you go to the second (or last if you add more). This way you won't have to change the `innerHTML` on any element and just toggle a class. Something like that could look like:

```
<form id="regForm" name="regForm" action="[NEED ACTION]" class="col-sm-6">
    ...
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <div style="float:right;">
            <button type="button" id="prevBtn" click="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
            <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
            <submit type="submit" class="hide" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```
function showTab(n) {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";

    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").classList.add('hide');
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").classList.remove('hide');
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").classList.remove('hide');
        document.getElementById("submitBtn").classList.add('hide');
    }

    fixStepIndicator(n)
}
```

For this to work you will need to fill in the `action` property for the form.

---

Another way you could do this without adding an extra element would be to change the `onClick` action for the next/submit button.

```
function showTab(n) {

    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    var nextSubmitBtn = document.getElementById("nextBtn");
    x[n].style.display = "block";

    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        nextSubmitBtn.textContent = "Submit";
        nextSubmitBtn.onClick = someSubmitFunc;
    } else {
        nextSubmitBtn.textContent = "Next";
        nextSubmitBtn.onClick = function () { nextPrev(1); };
    }

    fixStepIndicator(n)
}
```

This would allow you to keep the same HTML and handle the solution via JS. If you do this remember to keep the current `onClick` property on the "next" button as that will be the initial function ran (when you first click "next")

---

A couple tips and notes:

If you are only changing the text of an element (like from "next" to "submit") it would be best to use a function that only changes the text:

```
// Pure JS
element.textContnet = 'some text';

// jQuery
$element.text('some other text');
```

this will help prevent possible bugs (and potentially security risk) that can come from `innerHTML`.

You say you are using jQuery but it is only used in one line in the JS code presented. If that is the only line using jQuery library you could easily replace it and not include the library saving on you site size.

```
// jQuery way to add class (line 111)
$("#sdate").addClass("invalid");

// Pure JS equivalent 
document.getElementById('sdate').classList.add('invalid');
```

Both will get the job done (add a class) and if you prefer to use jQuery more power to you but if that is the only place you use it then this could be an alternative.

Comment: This is excellent! Thank you, this will help me out a lot, I have been working with PHP more this year so my brain is in PHP mode, getting used to JS is tricky.